# Where does aggregated data fit in in a REST JSON API and a mobile client?

Tags: json, api, rest, client-server, restkit

I have an iOS app talking with a REST JSON API. I have mapped the model resources 1-1 with the controllers/endpoints in the API. E.g. User (/users), Friendship (/friendships), Rating (/ratings), RatedObject (/rated_objects) etc. And on the device I'm using RestKit/CoreDate to store/sync all objects.

Now I start to get the need for different kind of aggregated data, e.g. different rating averages and rating counts on the RatedObject depending on the friendship type. I have solved it now by adding the data to the RatedObject type:

**RatedObject**

- name
- size
- ratingAverageFromCloseFriends
- ratingCountFromCloseFriends
- ratingAverageFromFamily
- ratingCountFromFamily
- ratingAverageFromAllFriends
- ratingCountFromAllFriends

But when it starts to get more kinds of aggregated data on different kind of objects, it is getting over hand. And I also sometimes need to get the average from only one specific friend, and that can't be added to the model.

I store all data locally on the iOS device, and the aggregated data should be easy to update from the server.

**How should I solve this and make it easy and natural for both the client and the server?**